# I have read contents of a file which I have done and then add up all the numbers in the file and find the average

Tags: java

```
    public static double value;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file :");
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String filename = scan.next();
    
    Scanner bru = new Scanner (new File(filename));
    
    int num = bru.nextInt();
            
    System.out.println("The file "+ filename +" has "+ num +" numbers in it");
            
            System.out.println("Content of file is");
            double total = 0.0; 
            
            while(bru.hasNextDouble()) 
            System.out.println(bru.nextDouble());
             value = bru.nextDouble();
                        
System.out.println(bru.nextDouble());
    
    }
}
```

When I run my code I get this error
"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at Project4.main(Project4.java:26)
```

"

If I add brackets to the while loop I don't get the error instead I it reads one double then skips the next and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using your variable to print from, rather than how you are doing it now. The "bru.nextDouble" is getting the next value every time you use it, which is why you are skipping values when you add the brackets. The value of "value" is what you want to print, not the "nextDouble" before it.

```
while(bru.hasNextDouble()) 
{
    value = bru.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Also, with using "bru.nextDouble" as many times as you do after checking "bru.hasNextDouble", you run the risk of trying to access data/values not in "bru" causing any number of exceptions. And the exception you are getting, `NoSuchElementException`, is likely the very exception that says you have already run out of data/values when you try to get the next one.

So, you also need to get rid of your last "System.out.println(bru.nextDouble());" and you should be able to run your current code, with the minor adjustment I suggest, without any exceptions due to running out of values.

There may be other issues and exceptions with your code, but I/we won't know that until you fix the problem you currently have.